# BASH - Capture string between a FIXED and 2 possible variables

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

To get what is between "**aa=**" and either **%** or empty

```
string = "aa=value%bb"
string2 = "bb=%aa=value"
```

The rule must work on both strings to get the value of "aa="

I would like a BASH LANGUAGE solution if possible.

Comment: I could not find a BASH LANGUAGE example via google searches. it seems somewhat too specific. ( due to 2 fixed variables )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
result=$(echo "$string" | grep -o 'aa=[^%]*')
result=${result:3} # remove aa=
```

`[^%]*` matches any sequence of characters that doesn't contain `%`, so it will stop when it gets to `%` or the end of the string. `$(result:3}` expands to the substring starting from character 3, which removes `aa=` from the beginning.

Comment: How do you exclude "aa=" ? ( from the grep result )

Comment: If you have a version of `grep` with PCRE, you could use a lookbehind to exclude it. I've shown how to remove it with a bash parameter expansion operator to get the substring starting from character 3.